# Cannot access site from host machine on a vagrant virtual machine

Tags: php, nginx, vagrant

I setup a nginx+mysql puphpet/vagrant image, with a virtual host "test.com". I mapped `test.com` to `192.168.56.101` on the host machine, and put an `index.php` file inside `/var/www/test`.

However, when I try opening the browser at the address test.com on the host machine I get no response. I feel like I'm missing something really simple, because I can ping `192.168.56.101`. I also checked nginx logs on the virtual machine, but they are empty. Any clues where the problem might be? Am I not supposed to use it this way? I can ssh into vagrant just fine, and also I can access the mysql db.

Comment: Did you configure your Vagrantfile to forward the necessary port(s) to your host machine?

Comment: I forgot to specify that I'm using puphpet, does it not take care of that automatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your Vagrantfile, you need to forward the port to your host machine.

For example map port 80 of the Vagrant machine to port 8080 of the host machine.

```
config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 80, host: 8080
```

Comment: This worked, however I found the puphpet documentation lacking in this regard. Are there any more documented alternatives?

Comment: Well ther is an official [Vagrantfile documentation](http://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/vagrantfile/index.html) available but it is not very good imho. Anyway, this [tutorial](http://www.sitepoint.com/vagrantfile-explained-setting-provisioning-shell/) is not bad.

Comment: My problem was that I was somehow expecting to see the site after editing the hosts file. But it seems that puphpet is behind a nat and so i also need to port forward. But this should be written in big letters on the front page or at least on the puphpet faq page. 

On a side note, every tutorial about puphpet (not vagrant, puphet specifically) does not mention this point, so i still feel like i'm missing something (how is it possbile that every other person omitted this passage in their tutorial?).

Comment: The port forwarding thing is Vargant specific. Not everybody uses puphpet with vagrant. That's why puphpet doesn't feel the need to mention it.

Comment: I've just found the problem. Even though the port forwarding trick worked indeed, there was no need to (as I saw in the various tutorials). The problem was related to the fact that i configured two vagrant machine on the same network. Cannot really say for sure what happened, but clearing both the VMs and the host only network on virtualbox let me access the vagrant box from the browser, without the need of a port forwarding. Thanks for the help.

Comment: In case it may help someone: the problem was that the address of the vm was ending in .1, and the same address was assigned to the host machine, causing a conflict on the host-only interface. The solution was to simply move the address of the vm to .2.